# Why is the convolution CDF of the product of two uniform variables in this form?

Tags: statistics

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are $U[0,1]$, the CDF of their product $U$, where $U=XY$ is:

\begin{equation}
\int_u^1 \bigg[\frac 1 x \times1\bigg] \, dx \quad \quad 0 < u < 1
\end{equation}

... and that's where I got stuck, why is the lower part of the integral $u$ and the term inside the integral $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: "... the CDF of the convolution of their product ..." The what?

Comment: I edited it as CDF of their product. In the book am using they refer to the product as 'convolution' of distributions

Comment: Are you trying to find the CDF of the product of two independent $U[0,1]$ variables $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, am trying to find the CDF of $U$, where $U= XY$, and both $X$ and $Y$ are uniform random variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is not quite right.  The derivation of the probability *density* function (pdf) for $U$ goes:$$\begin{split}f_{XY}(u) &= \int_\Bbb R f_X(x)~f_Y(u/x)~\left\lvert\dfrac{\partial (u/x)}{\partial u}\right\rvert\mathsf d x\quad\big[u\in[0;1]\big]\\ &= \int_\Bbb R\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u/x \leqslant 1}\lvert\tfrac 1x\rvert\mathrm d x\\ &= \int_{u\leqslant x\leqslant 1}\dfrac1x\mathsf d x\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u\leqslant 1}\\ &= \int_{u}^{1}\dfrac1x\mathsf d x\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant u\leqslant 1}\\ & = -\ln (u)\mathbf 1_{0< u\leqslant 1}\end{split}$$

Then the CDF is found by
$$\begin{split}F_{XY}(u)&=\int_0^u f_{XY}(x)\mathsf d x\\ & = \int_0^u-\ln(x)\mathsf d x\cdot\mathbf 1_{0< u\leqslant 1}+\mathbf 1_{1<u}\\ &= u(1-\ln (u))\cdot\mathbf 1_{0< u\leqslant 1}+\mathbf 1_{1<u}\end{split}$$

Comment: If I may ask, can I also get the derivation behind $\frac{d(u/x)}{d(u)}$?

Comment: @LinkL Ops, yes, that should be the partial derivative. $\tfrac{\partial (u/x)}{\partial u} = \tfrac 1 x\tfrac{\partial u}{\partial u}$

Comment: Ok, is my intuition behind $\frac{d(u/x)}{d(u)}$ correct? : we are dividing $d(u/x)$ by $d(u)$ so that we get the derivative of $\int_{R}f(y)d(y)=\int_{R}f(u/x)d(u/x)$? (equal to pdf of the $y=(u/x)$ variable)